Migrating Nuxt v2 SSR to React with SSR
I'm trying to incrementally migrate a Nuxt v2 application to use React components, while still supporting SSR.
I have this component to wrap React within the Vue application.
The problem I face is that all Vue lifecycle hooks with access to the component seem to happen client side.
beforeMount is client-side, but beforeCreate can't access the ref to mount the react HTML.
Is there any way to do this? I'm also looking into https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-render/#bundleRenderer as a possible option.
<template>
  <div ref="container" class="react-wrapper" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { createElement } from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import type { Root, Container } from 'react-dom/client';
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ReactWrapper',
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    component: {
      type: Function as PropType<string>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  beforeMount(): void {
      const container = this.$refs.container as Container;
      if (container) {
        this.reactRoot = createRoot(container);
        this.updateReactComponent();
      }
  },
  data(): { reactRoot: Root | null } {
    return {
      reactRoot: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateReactComponent(): void {
      if (process.client) {
        this.reactRoot?.render(
          createElement(this.component, {
            ...this.$attrs,
          })
        );
      } else {
        const container = this.$refs.container as HTMLDivElement;
        if (container) {
          const html = this.renderReactComponent();
          container.innerHTML = html;
        }
      }
    },
    renderReactComponent(): string {
      try {
        const html = renderToString(
          createElement(this.component, {
            ...this.$attrs
          })
        );
        return html;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          '[react-wrapper] Error rendering React component:',
          error
        );
        return '';
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    isClientRendered(): boolean {
      return process.client;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    $attrs: {
      deep: true,
      handler(): void {
        this.updateReactComponent();
      },
    },
  },
});
</script>


We I read React + SSR it makes me think about NextJS. I'm not so sure about mixing Nuxt (Vue) with React. That seems like a big endeavour to me. https://nextjs.org/

It could be something like <div v-if="isServer" v-html="reactHtml"><div v-else ref="reactContainer"> but I doubt it will be that simple. Making both frameworks use fully functional SSR with hydration looks like a can of worms, as this uncharted territory and likely requires to dig deep both into Nuxt internals to make it feasible. May not worth it if the goal is to save time on rewriting to React/Next
